# Excel VBA combobox skipped items

Tags: combobox, items

I'm dealing with old code that has a combobox in a gui coded in using VBA in a macro. there is a problem where the items in the combobox aren't complete, some items are skipped and don't appear when in the drop down. Does anyone know how to edit the contents of a combobox? how are you meant to set the items that appear in the drop down meno?

I tried to take a look at the database it is linking to and it's complete, but it is using an Autofilter that is set to False?